# Warnings are not getting suppressed even after using all the tricks I found online

Tags: php, error-handling, file-get-contents, suppress-warnings

I want to suppress warnings, I searched on SO, found some solutions but they aren't working.
I am getting Warning at following function(`file_get_contents`) when the internet connection is off. I know this functions requires internet connection, when the machine is not connected this function will show warning.

```
$hash = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$vid_id.php"));
```

first I tried using "@"

then I used `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);`

then I used `error_reporting(0);`

can anybody tell me how can I suppress these warnings?

Comment: If you are talking about not sending a warning to the client, a web browser, then you are on the right track. You _did_ restart the web server after changing the php configuration? And you _did_ make sure you modified the right configuration file?

Comment: @arkascha I wrote this in the same file where I have this function.

Comment: Then you certainly did _not_ follow any solution from SO or any guide found on google. I suggest you teach yourself the basics of php configuration. You need to reconfigure php for this.

Comment: then where should I write them?

Comment: and even @functionName() is not working

Comment: What do you mean: "where should I write them"? Did you even _read_ my comment?

Comment: yes, where do I write `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);` ?

Comment: Citation from above: "You need to reconfigure php for this." Sorry, we are not going to carry you home. You have to understand what you are doing yourself. We can only assist and offer help.

Comment: Ignoring errors/warning can be a _very_ bad idea. Why not implement a check to see if the host/you is/are online?

Comment: @nand I am testing it on localhost. And in this case its not ignoring, if you dont have have internet connection you cant do anything for that as you said to implement a check, I want to do this, only if in case the server is not connected or the the function fails by any reason, the user must not see the warning messages

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for a single file, you can suppress the warning using `@` like so:

```
$var = @file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$vid_id.php");
$hash = unserialize($var);
```

But if you don't want to display any errors, you can edit your `php.ini` file and change the value of `error_reporting` to `0`.

Make sure you restart Apache / webserver after making the changes to `php.ini` file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to supress warning only for this function `file_get_contents`